# Passing List Of Object As A Parameter From ajax request To Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

How to pass list of objects  as a parameter from ajax to controller.
Whenever I tried to pass quoteLineItemProducts as a parameter, controller shows the count as 0.
My **Jquery Code**

```
let lineItemProducts = new Array();

  this.checkCheckbox = function checkCheckboxes(id) {
    lineItemProducts = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
 $.ajax({
      url: "/Supplier/SupplierPurchaseOrderList/CreatSPOFromQuotes",
      data: JSON.stringify(lineItemProducts),
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (typeof (data) === "undefined") {
                    return;
                }
                if (data.data == null) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public void CreatSPOFromQuotes(List<QuoteIDS> id) // this id show count as 0
    {
      var quoteLineItems = id;

    }
```

**Thank you** in advance

Comment: It looks like you are sending a String and not a List.

Comment: @Twisty, can you please modify the above code.

Comment: What is the definition of `QuoteIDS`?

Comment: @taplar, its a class with only  Id as a property

Comment: Is it `Id` or `id`?

Comment: @taplar, It's Id

Comment: So it may be as simple as the case is not matching.  You are passing in object with `id` which is not mapped to that object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "Id": lineItemProducts})
```

instead of `data: JSON.stringify(lineItemProducts),`

Your ajax call will be

```
 $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("CreatSPOFromQuotes", "ControllerName")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({ "Id": lineItemProducts}),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             if (typeof (data) === "undefined") {
                    return;
                }
                if (data.data == null) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```